# How to upload a file from java to php

Tags: java, php, post, communication

I'm trying to upload a file from my computer to my webserver using Java & PHP.

**What works:** Client side, a java application turns a file into a byte array using:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
```

and this bytearray is sent via POST request to my webserver.

**What does not work:** The php file receives the bytearray and fails to turn it into its original file. php code:

```
$bytes = $_POST['file'];
$bytesStr = pack('C*', $bytes);
file_put_contents($_POST['fileName'], $bytesStr);
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: If you're just dumping the raw bytes into the POST body with no encoding, then you'll find those bytes in the [`php://input` stream](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php). If you want it to be caught by PHP's POST handler you need to encode the request as [`multipart/form-data`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2388).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to just use this:

```
$bytes = $_POST['file'];
$bytesStr = pack('C*', ...$bytes);
file_put_contents($_POST['fileName'], $bytesStr);
```